# To Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() or not to?

Tags: java, android, environment

I don't understand the message I'm getting with Eclipse. I added a "/sdcard" as a directory, and I got the warning:

```
Do not hardcode "/sdcard/"; use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() instead
```

So, obediently, I changed as demanded, but then I get an error:

```
The method getExternalStorageDirectory() is undefined for the type Environment
```

So??

Thanks!

Comment: The method is there, are you sure you're OK with the imports?

Comment: You are right, see my answer below. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some phones name their sd folder differently ex.:

In samsung phones, it is named `external_sd` , and your code will fail.

control+shift+o --> to add imports in eclipse, otherwise it should be [there](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html),

Comment: It still use the internal sd card even though you use it.

Comment: Right! The problem was that I had the call in a file called Environment.java itself, so Eclipse didn't give me the choice to import Environment. I changed the filename, and now it works fine. Thanks!!